# res.redirect() with an array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) 3.0.3.

```
return res.redirect('/finished/'+result[0].code)
```

In this code I query a mongodb and I have a result from a POST ajax method query, but I redirect from post url to a get url with param `result.code`

So I return to the user a page that contain only the code from result, but resently I discover that I have to add more information from the result to return to the user, so how can I redirect to /finished but passing an array instead a param...

Comment: With querystring module.

Already answered there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586716/node-js-send-and-receive-array-as-get-post-using-querystring

Comment: @Mattias i solve the problem with your comment, can you put as an answer, so i can tild that

Comment: @andrescabana86 what comment? Did you realized something due to my edit?